# Join a list of lists together into one list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which consists of many lists. Here is an example,

```
[
    [Obj, Obj, Obj, Obj],
    [Obj],
    [Obj],
    [
        [Obj,Obj],
        [Obj,Obj,Obj]
    ]
]
```

Is there a way to join all these items together as one list, so the output will be something like

```
[Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj,Obj]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here's [one way to do it](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216879.html):

```
def flatten(lst):
    for elem in lst:
        if type(elem) in (tuple, list):
            for i in flatten(elem):
                yield i
        else:
            yield elem
```

Please note, this creates a generator, so if you need a list, wrap it in `list()`:

```
flattenedList = list(flatten(nestedList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from MonkeySage, [here](http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html):

```
def iter_flatten(iterable):
  it = iter(iterable)
  for e in it:
    if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
      for f in iter_flatten(e):
        yield f
    else:
      yield e
```